# how to scrape the same element tags in beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

in example i have :

```
<div class="col-sm-10" itemprop="articleBody">
 <p><strong>Bisnis.com</strong>, SURABAYA - Kalangan pengusaha bidang teknologi informasi (TI) di Jawa Timur menyebut selama pandemi usaha sektor TI mengalami kekurangan tenaga kerja mengingat tren penggunaan teknologi internet semakin meningkat.</p>
<p>Wakil Ketua Komite Tetap Usaha Telekomunikasi dan Data Kamar Dagang dan Indonesia (Kadin) Jatim, Achmad Fauzi mengatakan kondisi pandemi yang mengharuskan masyarakat untuk bekerja dari rumah akhirnya memaksa mereka untuk menggunakan TI sebagai solusi media penghubung sosial.</p>
<p>"Kondisi ternyata menjadi peluang bagi industri informasi dan telekomunikasi untuk berkembang lebih pesat, meskipun memang sektor usaha lainnya sedang mengalami kontraksi," katanya, Selasa (12/5/2020).</p><div class="baca-juga"><table><tr><th>Baca Juga : <span> <a href="https://teknologi.bisnis.com/read/20200413/101/1226269/pandemi-covid-19-diprediksi-tekan-pengeluaran-belanja-teknologi-informasi?utm_source=Desktop&amp;utm_medium=Artikel&amp;utm_campaign=BacaJuga_1" target="_blank" title="Pandemi Covid-19 Diprediksi Tekan Pengeluaran Belanja Teknologi Informasi">Pandemi Covid-19 Diprediksi Tekan Pengeluaran Belanja Teknologi Informasi</a> </span></th></tr></table></div>
```

and my code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://search.bisnis.com/?q=tenaga+kerja+bidang+teknologi&per_page='

# for page in range(1,10):
page = 1
req = requests.get(url + str(page))
html = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
listBerita = html.findAll('ul', attrs={'class', 'list-news'})

links =[link.get('href') for link in html.findAll('a', attrs={'class', 'icon'})]
for link in links:
    req = requests.get(link)
    pgNews = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
    title = pgNews.find('h1').text
    news = pgNews.find('div', attrs={'class', 'col-sm-10'}).p.text
    print(news)
```

My expected output is all of the p tags, but the output of the code only takes the first p tag. how to do it so that the output matches my expectations, I need your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value from all p tag under the div class use `find_all()` 
Please note 3rd link doesn't contain the `class name` you are after.So provided if condition.

```
for link in links:
    req = requests.get(link)
    pgNews = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
    title = pgNews.find('h1').text
    news = pgNews.find('div', attrs={'class', 'col-sm-10'})
    if news:
        print([new.text for new in  pgNews.find('div', attrs={'class', 'col-sm-10'}).find_all('p') if new])
```

Output would be like.

```
['Bisnis.com, SURABAYA - Kalangan pengusaha bidang teknologi informasi (TI) di Jawa Timur menyebut selama pandemi usaha sektor TI mengalami kekurangan tenaga kerja mengingat tren penggunaan teknologi internet semakin meningkat.', 'Wakil Ketua Komite Tetap Usaha Telekomunikasi dan Data Kamar Dagang dan Indonesia (Kadin) Jatim, Achmad Fauzi mengatakan kondisi pandemi yang mengharuskan masyarakat untuk bekerja dari rumah akhirnya memaksa mereka untuk menggunakan TI sebagai solusi media penghubung sosial.', '"Kondisi ternyata menjadi peluang bagi industri informasi dan telekomunikasi untuk berkembang lebih pesat, meskipun memang sektor usaha lainnya sedang mengalami kontraksi," katanya, Selasa (12/5/2020).', 'Data Badan Pusat Statistik (BPS) Jatim mencatat, pertumbuhan lapangan usaha informasi dan komunikasi pada kuartal I/2020 tercatat mengalami pertumbuhan sebesar 9,77 persen, meningkat dibanding kuartal I/2019 yang sebesar 6,40 persen.', 'Sementara PDRB Jatim untuk sektor IT atas harga berlaku di kuartal I/2020 mencapai Rp28,204 triliun, naik dibanding tahun lalu pada periode yang sama sebesar Rp25,155 triliun.', '"Kondisi ini didorong oleh meningkatnya trafik data sejak pemberlakuan Work From Home (WFH) dan School From Home (SFH)," katanya.', 'Hanya saja, kata Fauzi, peningkatan kinerja industri TI ini tidak diimbangi dengan tenaga kerja yang mengerjakan pemerintaan pasar untuk pemasangan fiber optik.', '"Kami cukup kelabakan mencari tenaga kerja, untuk melayani satu klien saja, kami kemarin sempat kekurangan 100 tenaga kerja pemasangan fiber optik. WFH dan SFH ini membuat masyarakat akhirnya berbondong-bondong memasang Indihome," ujar Fauzi yang juga merupakan General Manager Javadwipa Group itu.', 'Fauzi menambahkan, Kadin Jatim merekomendasikan kepada seluruh pebisnis sektor IT untuk membuat perencanaan kerja jangka pendek dan jangka panjang di saat pandemi ini agar sektor IT bisa tetap berjuang melayani konsumen bahkan sampai pandemi Covid-19 berakhir.', 'Simak berita lainnya seputar topik artikel ini, di sini : ']
['Bisnis.com, JAKARTA - Huawei menghadirkan platform daring untuk memperkuat kerja sama dengan para operator dan mitranya di seluruh dunia dengan membagi pengalaman suksesnya di bidang 5G dan membangun target jaringan yang makin baik.', 'Peng Song, President Carrier BG Marketing dan Solution Sales Department. Huawei, mengimbau industri teknologi, informasi, dan komunikasi (TIK) agar terus bersatu dan bersinergi guna membangun dunia yang lebih baik.', '“Tahun 2020 menandai dimulainya dekade ketiga abad ke-21. Transformasi digital dunia akan semakin mengakselerasi munculnya peluang-peluang baru, namun di sisi lain juga melahirkan tantangan baru bagi para operator telekomunikasi maupun industri,” ujarnya, seperti dikutip Senin (27/4/2020).', 'Menurutnya, untuk menjawab peluang dan tantangan tersebut, para operator harus membidik target jaringan yang lebih tangguh, terotomatisasi, dan cerdas. Rencana dan aktivitas jaringan tahunan mereka harus diarahkan untuk mencapai tujuan ini.\xa0', 'Peng Song menjelaskan bahwa Huawei meluncurkan platform dari 5G+, Better World untuk memperkuat kerja sama dengan para operator dan mitra di seluruh dunia. “Melalui platform ini, kami akan membagi pengalaman sukses kami dan membangun target jaringan yang lebih baik," tuturnya.', 'Pada online summit tersebut, Huawei juga merilis buku putih, berjudul Technology Against Pandemic: Insights and Practice on Telecom Networks. Buku putih ini menyajikan wawasan mendalam mengenai jaringan global serta menjelaskan peran penting jaringan telekomunikasi dalam melawan pandemi.', 'Jaringan telekomunikasi yang stabil telah banyak membantu masyarakat menggerakkan aktivitas vital secara daring, seperti pendidikan daring, belanja daring, serta bekerja secara jarak jauh (remote).', '\xa0Kegiatan belajar-mengajar terus dapat berjalan dan produktivitas terus berkelanjutan di saat sekolah dan kantor-kantor ditutup untuk sementara.', 'Buku putih ini juga menjelaskan tentang beragam keberhasilan yang telah dilakukan oleh para operator global dalam mengatasi pandemi dengan mendayagunakan jaringan.', 'Sebagai contoh, mereka memperkenalkan 5G, AI, fiber 10G PON, dan teknologi canggih lainnya yang menjadikan makin banyak aplikasi yang dapat dimanfaatkan untuk turut memerangi pandemi secara lebih efisien.', 'Simak berita lainnya seputar topik artikel ini, di sini :  huawei, buku putih ']
['Bisnis.com, JAKARTA - Perputaran tenaga kerja yang tidak dibarengi dengan kompetensi yang cukup di sektor jasa keuangan menjadi tantangan utama saat ini.', 'Ketua Umum Asosiasi Sistem Pembayaran Indonesia (ASPI) Anggoro Eko Cahyo mengatakan saat ini belum ada penerapan standar kompetensi dan lembaga sertifikasi. Sementara, turn over atau perputaran tinggi, sehingga kompetensi dari tenaga kerja di sektor tersebut perlu kembali dipertanyakan. Belum lagi hal ini menyebabkan risiko biaya operasional yang semakin meningkat.', '"Perputaran antar kami [industri keuangan] semakin tinggi padahal kompetensinya belum tentu. Standar kompetensi akan menjadi sangat baik, memang tidak bisa menghentikan turn over, tetapi paling turn over-nya adalah orang-orang yang berpotensi ketika berpindah ke tempat lain," katanya dalam seminar dengan tema Strategi Meningkatkan Kualitas SDM di bidang Sistem Pembayaran Dalam Menghadapi Era Digitalisasi dan Persaingan Global, Senin (9/3/2020).', 'Oleh karena itu, Anggoro menyatakan ASPI akan mendukung Bank Indonesia dan Kementerian Ketenagakerjaan dalam mendorong standardisasi kompetensi di bidang Sistem Pembayaran dan Pengelolaan Uang Rupiah atau SPPUR. Asosiasi juga akan mengawal implementasi dari rencana tersebut, seiring dengan perkembangan sistem pembayaran yang berjalan sangat cepat akibat digitalisasi.', 'Pada Senin (9/3/2020), Bank Indonesia bersama dengan Kementerian Ketenagakerjaan dan Badan Nasional Sertifikasi Profesi (BNSP) melakukan pendandatanganan Nota Kesepahaman (NK) mengenai Kerja Sama dalam rangka Standardisasi Kompetensi di Bidang SPPUR.', 'Kerja sama tersebut menyepakati tiga langkah penguatan. Pertama, yaitu pengembangan standardisasi kompetensi di bidang SPPUR. Kedua, percepatan pembentukan kelembagaan pelatihan kerja dan sertifikasi profesi di bidang SPPUR serta pengembangan perangkat pelatihan kerja dan sertifikasi kompetensi, antara lain tenaga pelatih dan asesor, serta skema sertifikasi.', 'Ketiga, akan dilakukan pengakuan kesetaraan (mutual recognition arrangement) sertifikasi kompetensi SPPUR dengan sertifikasi profesi sejenis yang ditebitkan, baik di dalam negeri maupun di luar negeri.', 'Pelaku SPPUR yang dimaksud merupakan SDM di bank dan lembaga non bank yang menyelenggarakan jasa sistem pembayaran dan pengelolaan uang rupiah.', 'Pada saat ini jumlah SDM SPPUPE mencapai 280.000 pegawai dari berbagai level. Penerapan Standardisasi Kompetensi di Bidang SPPUR pun akan diterapkan secara bertahap mulai 1 Juli 2020.', 'Simak berita lainnya seputar topik artikel ini, di sini : ']..so on.
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is very very helpful, and it solved my other problems, and this answer gave me new knowledge,

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd link
https://koran.bisnis.com/read/20200318/446/1214609/dampak-implementasi-teknologi-perbankan-penurunan-sdm-bank-berlanjut does not contain the `<div class="col-sm-10">` balise. Instead, the balise is `<div class="col-sm-12">`, and the paragraphes are not build with `<p>...</p>` balises.
This is why it is not working.
Fuurthermore, you need to bo log in to view the full paragraph

I suggest

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://search.bisnis.com/?q=tenaga+kerja+bidang+teknologi&per_page='

# for page in range(1,10):
page = 1
req = requests.get(url + str(page))
html = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
listBerita = html.findAll('ul', attrs={'class', 'list-news'})

links = html.findAll('a', attrs={'class', 'icon'})
for link in links:
    link = link.get('href')
    print(link)
    req = requests.get(link)

    pgNews = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
    title = pgNews.find('h1').text
    news = pgNews.find('div', attrs={'class', 'description'})
    try:
        news = news.find('p').text
    except:
        news = news.text[:300]  # If fail, you "at least" show the 1st 300 characters
    print('title=', title, '\nnews=', news)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help, your answer gives me new knowledge